# finding the volume of the solid via disk or washer method

Tags: calculus

the question is: $y = 1/4x^2$, $x = 2$, $y = 0$; about the $y$-axis

I tried to draw it out, but I can't figure this stuff out. The graphing is the hardest part for me because I don't know what to do to graph whatever information is given and then make some sort of reasonable deduction about what to plug in where for either disk or washer method.

Comment: Is it $\frac{1}{4}x^2$ aka $\frac{x^2}{4}$ or is it something else?

Comment: yes @AndréNicolas

Comment: what do you mean $y=0, x=2$

Comment: well that`s literally how it`s given in the textbook question.

Comment: it says "find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line. Sketch the region, the solid, and a typical disk or washer.

Comment: then, the question says: "y = (1/4)(x^2), x = 2, y = 0; about the y-axis

Comment: Draw the curve $y=x^2/4$, familiar probably, pretty standard parabola. The region is probably in the first quadrant, **below** the parabola, and to the left of the vertical line $x=2$. You will find shells easiest.

Comment: okay thankyou @AndréNicolas

Comment: Cylindrical shells are best. If not, integrate with respect to $y$, disk, outer radius $2$, inner radius $2\sqrt{y}$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\int_0^2\pi x^2(\frac14x^2)dx=\frac\pi4\left[\frac{x^5}5\right]_0^2=\frac{8\pi}5$

Comment: where does the pi go to?

Answer (score 1):

The region that is being rotated is the part of the first quadrant that is *below* the easily drawn parabola $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$ and to the left of the vertical line $x=2$.

We are rotating about the $y$-axis. Imagine taking a slice of the solid perpendicular to the $y$-axis, "at" $y$. The cross-section is a disk with a circular hole in it. The outer radius of the cross-section is $2$, and the inner radius is $2\sqrt{y}$. So the area of cross-section is $\pi\left(2^2-(2\sqrt{y})^2\right)$. Note that when $x=2$, we have $y=1$. Thus the volume is
$$\int_0^1 \pi\left(4-4y\right)\,dy.$$
Integrate. We get $2\pi$.

**Another way:** Alternately, we can use the Method of Cylindrical Shells. Take a thin horizontal slice of width "$dx$" at $x$, and rotate it about the $y$-axis. We get a thin cylindrical shell of radius $x$, height $\frac{x^2}{4}$, and thickness $dx$. Thus the volume of the shell is approximately $(2\pi x)(x^2/4)\,dx$. Now "add up" (integrate) from $x=0$ to $x=2$. Our volume is
$$\int_0^2 (2\pi)\left(\frac{x^3}{4}\right)\,dx.$$
Calculate. Again we get $2\pi$.